# Sharing Directory between builds aka sharing node_modules

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

`yarn` takes a lot of time on `vsts` `hosted agent` due to more than few dependencies .

Our `monorepo` contains three somewhat identical but totally different apps which share lot of `node` dependencies.

Each app is very huge and takes considerable time to build. So we  build individual app based on [path filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/triggers#path-filters-in-vsts-and-team-foundation-services-tfs)

Release contains `artifacts` from all three builds

#### What I need

- download `node modules` once
- use same downloaded dependencies in three different conditional builds
- release app after all or any build with `artifacts` latest for each build

any pointers how to configure this

Comment: What have you tried with that?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT I havent tried any thing yet as i'm new to vsts.
We already have a Build setuped but it takes very long time, by building same things which can be skipped.
I tried to find some information in docs but couldn't find any.

Comment: Can you achieve that on your local Dev machine? If that not work on local ,then it's difficult to achieve on TFS. Generally if you build the apps separately, then it will download the dependencies evry time. Alternatively you can add a `copy task` to copy the dependencies for each App, but it will still spend some time for the copy action. Check if this article helps: [Referencing Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668956.aspx)

Comment: So you are using Hosted Agent and have three build definitions to run three builds, and you want to share the node_modules folders between these three builds?

Comment: @eddie yes exactly

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any way to do this with Hosted Agent. The Hosted Agent is a group of virtual machines hosted on Azure. Every time you queue a new build, it will initialize an available agent from these machines with a clean environment. So the build machine you used may different for every build. And when the build is finished, the files downloaded/generated during the build will also be cleared. So there isn't any way to share the files between them.